# Django: How to modify the value of a Model attribute

Tags: python, django, sqlite

Say I have a Django `Person` model connected to a sqlite3 database:

> ```
> class Person(models.Model):
>     name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
>
>     def __unicode__(self):
>         return self.name
> ```

Then I create an instance

> ```
> person = Person.objects.get_or_create(name="Henry")[0]
> ```

How can I now change the name of `Henry`?
I tried

> Person.objects.get(pk=1).name = "Alfred"

(where `pk=1` corresponds to the primary key (?) of `Henry`) but the name remains `Henry`, as I can see in my Django Admin.

Answer (score 3):

You have to save your change :

```
person = Person.objects.get(pk=1)
person.name = "Alfred"
person.save()
```

Comment: good to know, wonderful. didn't see this anywhere in the tutorial.

Comment: Django models are a bit tricky to use, indeed, but very powerful after you learn how to use them.

Comment: I guess a better understanding of the underlying database also helps  lot